# Simple monitoring of an ActiveMQ "Classic" queue over time

Tags: activemq-classic, monitoring

I'm using ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.16.4. I wanted something like the default web-console graph, but instead of split by queue name, to have number of queue entries over a day or couple of days.

I couldn't see anything simply to change in the `queueGraph.jsp` that I could hack on to change the for each row to for each time.

Didn't really want to have to implement a custom monitoring solution just to see the messages coming in and being processed over time.

Is anyone aware of a way of doing this in the default ActiveMQ stack - or is the only solution to implement something else to store the queue length at time periods.

Comment: Version 5.16.4

No @JustinBertram  more just over a day or couple of days.  I guess I'd end up having ot write somethign to externalise the data.  Was just hoping there was something built in for a simple graph with messages per hour or something like that.

Comment: Did you get this sorted?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a built-in mechanism to do this in ActiveMQ "Classic." I think the simplest solution would be to set up an instance of Prometheus and configure the broker with the [JMX Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter).

ActiveMQ Artemis has a built-in feature called ["Message Counters"](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#message-counters) that can do this kind of thing. It also has tighter integration with Prometheus via the [Prometheus metrics plugin](https://github.com/jbertram/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin). General information about exporting metrics in ActiveMQ Artemis can be found in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/metrics.html).